# Three.js: re-orient axis of rotation

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js

I have an airplane mesh with its tail at (0,0,0) and its nose at (a,b,c). I want to point the nose at (e,f,g) and leave the tail at (0,0,0). No extraneous rotations should be introduced, just the one simple rotation to repoint the plane.

Perhaps another way of saying this: I would like to work with a different coordinate system when calculating the plane's rotations. In my example (e,f,g) would ideally be (1,0,0) so I could more simply calculate some rotations.

This may be more of a pure maths problem, but I'm trying to implement this in three.js and would like to know what is the best series of calls to effect this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create the desired quaternion:

```
var vFrom = new THREE.Vector3( a, b, c ).normalize();
var vTo = new THREE.Vector3( e, f, g ).normalize();

var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromUnitVectors( vFrom, vTo );
```

You will find it convenient if your geometry is oriented so the airplane faces the positive-z axis.

Therefore, define `( e, f, g )` to be `( 0, 0, 1 )`.

Now, apply the quaternion to the mesh's geometry:

```
geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationFromQuaternion( quaternion ) );
```

At this point, the nose of the airplane should point in the direction of vector `vTo`, which in your case, will be the positive-z axis. (Hopefully, the airplane is level at this point. If it is not, you will have to apply another transform to fix it.)

To re-orient the airplane using natural yaw, pitch, and roll, set

```
mesh.rotation.order = 'YXZ'. // the default is `XYZ`
```

Now you can set the airplane's orientation like so:

```
mesh.rotation.set( pitch_radians, yaw_radians, roll_radians );
```

Everything should be very intuitive.

three.js r.69

Comment: I could call applyMatrix() on the mesh (object3d) instead of the geometry, right? That's what I was expecting, and now I'm scratching my head trying to see the difference.

Comment: By applying the transform to the geometry first, the geometry is oriented as desired, and `mesh.rotation` remains at `( 0, 0, 0 )`.